# Changing layout of titles for annexes

Tags: titles

I want to have a specific typesetting for the titles in my annexes.

Currently, the titles are as follows, achieved by the code below:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Annex \Alph{section}}
```

However, I need to have the following:

The section should be labeled as "Annex A Full Output.."
The subsection as "A.1 Failure locations"
And figures/tables should be numbered as "Figure/Table A.1, A.2..."

How can this be done?

[image]